# loading excel file into pandas dataframe flask app running with mod_wsgi apache that user uploaded

Tags: python, excel, apache, flask

I have a flask app where a user uploads files to an upload folder. Then I want to take those files and read them into pandas dataframes for further processing. The process works fine using app.run() on my localhost. I am trying to get it to work on aws with mod_wsgi and apache.

```
    @app.route('/uploader', methods=['POST'])
    def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            filenames=[]
            uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
            file.save(os.path.join(app.root_path,app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            filenames.append(filename)
        plotfiles=parse_all(filenames)

    def parse_all(filenames):
        folder_path=os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
        for f in filenames:
            f=send_from_directory(folder_path,filename))
            excel_file=pandas.ExcelFile(f)
            #do more stuff
```

I get the error `ValueError: Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io.`

The file is uploaded to the upload folder correctly but obviously not fetched correctly into the `f` variable. The type of f is `<class 'flask.wrappers.Response'>` and `f.__dict__` returns

`{'_on_close': [], 'response': [], 'headers': Headers([('X-Sendfile', u'/var/www/html/cluster_app/data/filename.xlsx'), ('Content-Length', u'82668'), ('Content-Type', u'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'), ('Cache-Control', u'public, max-age=43200'), ('Expires', u'Tue, 07 Jun 2016 22:59:11 GMT'), ('ETag', u'"1465297151.54-82668-755509703"')]), '_status_code': 200, '_status': '200 OK', 'direct_passthrough': True}`

When running on my localhost on my machine there was a .file attribute in the response, now response is empty. Printing folder_path gives `/var/www/html/cluster_app/data` which is the uploads folder.

I'm very green on flask/wsgi/apache. Would really appreciate some advice on how to access the file system in my code.

Comment: try this `excel_file=pandas.ExcelFile(f,engine='xlrd')`.

Comment: thanks, I tried this but get the same error

Comment: I think you should mention the file path as a URL like `excel_file=pandas.ExcelFile(file://path/to/your/file)`.

Comment: Have a look at similar error:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436827/get-data-from-sheets-in-excell/49534285#49534285](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436827/get-data-from-sheets-in-excell/49534285#49534285)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`f=send_from_directory(folder_path,filename))`

I use

`f = open(os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))`

to open the file. I just assumed `send_from_directory` would work as it does when I used flask `app.run()` on my localhost. I'd still like to know why `send_from_directory` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suggest you check the flask documentation about upload files [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/) and later re-check your code.